# Wordpress plug-in to instantly reply to a form?

Tags: email, forms, wordpress

Does anyone know if there is a wordpress plug-in which lets you set up a form which has an email field, among others.
The form, after filled in, would:

1. send the content of the form fields to an email address (name:joe, phone number: 555 etc)
2. send an instance response to the email provided ('thanks for your contribution')
3. add email address to an internal database (which is exportable) within the wprdpress admin

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will accomplish your task and more - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formstack/

Answer (score 0):

cformsII from Delicious Day is what you're looking for.  Customizable, easy to set up, and can be set up to track all form submissions.  Find it at http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/